# Zero if field is left blank on create/update instead of NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, named `Price`. I wanted the field to be zero `0` instead of `null` when the user create new/update prices for the fields that were left empty.

My input `form` for `Price`.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@price) do |f| %>    
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
    <%= f.label :special_Price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price_2, :hide_label => true %>

    <%= f.submit class: 'button btn btn-success' %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', prices_path, class: "button btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My `create_prices.rb`

```
class CreatePrices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :prices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :price
      t.integer :price_2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My `price_controller.rb` (relevant code only)

```
  def create
    @price = Price.new(price_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @price.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: "index" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @price }
        flash[:success] = "Price was successfully created!"
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @price.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @price.update(price_params)
        format.html { redirect_to action: "index" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @price }
        flash[:success] = "Price was successfully updated!"
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @price.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_price
      @price = Price.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def price_params
      params.require(:price).permit(:name, :description, :catogery_id, :price, :price_2)
    end
```

My attempt: I tried to add  `:default => 0` and `:nil => false` to my create model file (as suggested in a few related posts in stackoverflow). I also read that `change` is smart enough to update the field to `0` if the field is left empty. However, it did not work for me, when I leave my fields blank on create/update, the fields are still blank (instead of showing zero) after save/update.

```
 class CreatePrices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :prices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :catogery_id
      t.integer :price, :default => 0, :nil => false //also tried "default: 0", does not work either
      t.integer :price_2, :default => 0, :nil => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Possible attempt: I was also thinking to use `if else` statement in my controller to check if it is `blank`. However, it will be too much of code if I have 20 input fields in the form. Is there any efficient way that I can do to achieve what I was trying to do?

This is a personal project that I am doing, not school/work related question. Please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: `t.integer :price, default: 0` on migration should do this. please share relevant lines from your controller.

Comment: What do you 'does not work' - the migration fails? defaults of null are still being added? some other error?

Comment: Did you rollback and re-run the migration after adding the default?

Comment: @David It is still showing NULL on DB instead of 0;

Comment: @marmeladze I added the code from controller.

Comment: @mikej I destroyed the entire DB and migrate + seed all my data. Attempted a few times.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've screwed up something.

Here is a fresh rails project.

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.1
$ rails new lorem
$ rails g scaffold price name:string description:text price:integer  price_special:integer

$ rake db:create
Created database 'db/development.sqlite3'
Created database 'db/test.sqlite3'
$ rake db:migrate
== 20161226222013 CreatePrices: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:prices)
   -> 0.0064s
== 20161226222013 CreatePrices: migrated (0.0066s) ============================

$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 24439
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
2.3.1 :001 > p = Price.new
 => #<Price id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, price: 0, price_special: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.3.1 :002 > p.name = 'foo'
 => "foo" 
2.3.1 :003 > p.description = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
 => "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" 
2.3.1 :004 > p.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.4ms)  INSERT INTO "prices" ("name", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "foo"], ["description", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"], ["created_at", 2016-12-26 22:22:45 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-26 22:22:45 UTC]]
   (91.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.3.1 :005 > p
 => #<Price id: 1, name: "foo", description: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", price: 0, price_special: 0, created_at: "2016-12-26 22:22:45", updated_at: "2016-12-26 22:22:45"> 
2.3.1 :006 >
```

migration file

```
class CreatePrices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :prices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :price, default: 0
      t.integer :price_special, default: 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've put this just show that if you've done things like that, it should work.

Please provide more details.

**UPDATE**

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality

```
#add validations to model    
class Price < ApplicationRecord
  validates :price, :price_special, numericality: true
end
```

This will provide useful error messages.

Default form

[image]

If I set price and special_price blank and submit form it will produce such messages.

[image]

If you want to skip those and want to handle things in your controller (which is not a good solution),

**UPDATE 2**

By default if you have default values set for your tables, and if you create forms "the rails way", they take those default values.

```
<%= f.number_field :price %>
```

in above example will produce

```
<input value="0" name="price[price]" id="price_price" type="number">
```

in case if your user change those zeros to blank, you should try this.

```
2.3.1 :034 > p = Price.new
 => #<Price id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, price: 0, price_special: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.3.1 :035 > params #url params mockup
 => {:name=>"lorem", :description=>"ipsum", :price=>nil, :price_special=>nil} 
2.3.1 :036 > params.each do |k,v|
2.3.1 :037 >     p[k] = ( v.present? ? v : 1 ) #1 or any default value
2.3.1 :038?>   end
2.3.1 :043 > p
 => #<Price id: nil, name: "lorem", description: "ipsum", price: 1, price_special: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

also have a look those 
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F

Comment: I tried to create using the console way like what you did. Everything is perfect, as in 0 for those fields that have not assigned to a value. However, when I tried to fill in the form by leaving the fields empty, it will become NULL.

Comment: My main goal is to allow users to leave the field empty and the program will handle the empty field by setting it to zero. I don't want the user to individually set every field to zero before saving it. When there are two fields, it's fine. What if there are 20 fields, and 10 of them are not used. It will be inefficient for the person to enter the information into all the fields.

Comment: If you place `value: 0` at the input field, user has to delete the 0 in order to insert a new value. The extra steps are causing inefficient. I am looking for an efficient way to implement this feature.